# Difference between `eye(2)` and `[1, 0; 0, 1]` in automatic broadcasting

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, broadcast

I want to subtract a vector `v` from each column of the identity matrix in Octave (version 4.4.1), e.g. `v = [1; 1]`.

Why is automatic broadcasting not working for the command `eye`?

`eye(2) - [1; 1]` says

> error: operator -: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x2, op2 is 1x2)

while `bsxfun(@minus,eye(2),[1; 1])` and `[1, 0; 0, 1] - [1; 1]` both yield

> `[0, -1; -1, 0]`

Why does Octave make this distinction in automatic broadcasting? Why is `eye(2)` not equivalent to `[1, 0; 0, 1]`?

---

Note: In Matlab R2016a, I do not have automatic broadcasting, so I can only use `bsxfun(@minus,eye(2),[1; 1])`, which is consistent and thus less confusing.

Comment: what version of Matlab/Octave do you work with? The automatic broadcasting was changed by Matlab several times -- I think, there was a major change e.g. in 2016b (but don't nail me to this)

Comment: @max: I have updated my question accordingly. I can confirm that Matlab 2016a does not have automatic broadcasting for my scenario. Do you know whether `eye(2)` is equivalent to `[1, 0; 0, 1]`? I really do not understand Octave's distinction between the two.

Comment: Type `isequal([1, 0; 0, 1], eye(2))` you'll have the answer wether they are equal or not

Comment: @Adam they may be "equal" but they're not "equivalent". Similar to single vs double-quoted strings.

Comment: I have just checked on matlab at work (R2018b) and can confirm `eye(2)-[1;1]` produces the expected broadcasted result. Furthermore for anyone interested (with reference to my answer below), in matlab, `eye(2)` returns a standard full matrix rather than a memory-optimised object like in Octave.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou What do you mean that `[1 0; 0 1]` and `eye(2)` are not equivalent? They produce the exact same result

Comment: @LuisMendo in matlab, yes. they are both full matrices. In octave however, this is not the case. The first creates an object of type "matrix" (class double), whereas the latter creates an object of type "diagonal matrix" (class double). Create the two and compare "whos" in matlab and octave to see what I mean. Also see my answer below. The `typeinfo` function only exists in octave, but from what I understand it refers to the type of otherwise built-in objects (rather than user-created classes, which are a different mechanism), and alludes to how these types are implemented under the hood.

Comment: @Tasos Ah, I see. I’m not that familiar with Octave, but I remember something similar with colon expressions creating a “range” object rather than a vector

Comment: @DaveFar: DaveFar thank you for the addition, however, I have reverted this, since the `[ <specialised matrix> ]` syntax is not guaranteed to convert a specialised matrix into its normal (i.e. 'full') version. The appropriate function to perform this is is the `full` function (e.g. `full(eye(2))`, `full(sparse[1,0;0,1]))`, `full(1:10)`, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical answer for this (at least in octave) is that eye(2) does not produce an identical type as [1,0;0,1]; it produces a memory-efficient diagonal matrix, and octave does not have a broadcastable minus function implemented for the diagonal matrix type (yet*).

```
> typeinfo([1,0;0,1])
ans = matrix

> typeinfo(eye(2))
ans = diagonal matrix

> diag([1,1])- [1;1]
% error: operator -: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x2, op2 is 2x1)

> full( diag([1,1]) ) - [1;1]
% works
```

In fact, you would get the same issue if you tried to broadcast the equivalent sparse matrix:

```
> sparse([1,0;0,1]) - [1;1]
%error: operator -: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x2, op2 is 2x1)
```

If you want to perform broadcasting without casting back into a full matrix (e.g. via `full(eye(2)) - [1; 1]`), you can fall back on `bsxfun`, which is a function designed to perform broadcasting explicitly.

Having said that, the output of bsxfun is a normal matrix, which means you would get the same result if you 'collected' the `full` matrix from the specialised type first, and then use broadcasting as expected, therefore I doubt there's any efficiency gains from using bsxfun in this case. On the contrary, bsxfun can incur a performance penalty when used with computationally costly antipatterns such as `bsxfun( @(x,y) x-y, eye(2), [1;1] )` (which is very commonly seen, but thankfully not what you did).

---

<sub>* Having said that, if this isn't a bug, then it could sure be a feature. It's worth opening a ticket on the octave bugtracker (if there isn't one already!).</sub>

Comment: There is indeed [a submitted bug for this issue](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?35787) (pretty old one though ...)

Answer (score 0):

in R2016b Matlab changed the *implicit expansion* arithmetic, see this [blog-post from Loren - on the art of Matlab](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). There is another useful post [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/11/10/more_thoughts_about_implicit_expansion/).

Basically it makes Matlab more user-friendly for not-programming-loving people, who just want to get things done, who are mostly engineers (like me). So Matlab will now expand vectors if they don't fit to a matrix in one dimension (this dimension will be expanded). This is good and bad at the same time. Your code gets shorter and more readable (since you don't need to use the `repmat` to expand it manually) but it also makes your code prone to flaws in your code that will be overlooked and cause strange errors much more down the pipe.
In any case, if code generation becomes involved, you will still need to expand vectors explicitly with `repmat`.

Comment: In all seriousness though, between bsxfun / implicit expansion and repmat, expansion is much preferable. In most cases, repmat tends to come with a hefty computational penalty.

Comment: while an interesting history lesson, this doesn't appear to address the question regarding the different treatment of eye().

Comment: Asking why `eye(2) - [1,1]` does not work relates exactly to implicit expansion as the original matlab could only subtract scalars or matrices of equal size (and not implicitly expand the 1x2 vector to a 2x2 matrix). Thus, it is a actually answering the original question @NickJ

Comment: But MATLAB catching up with Octave regarding implicit expansion doesn't address the original question of why `eye(2) - [1,1]` doesn't work when `[1,0;0,1] - [1,1]` does.